# Can records be "locked" in a Microsoft Access application

Tags: ms-access

I would like to design a database application using Microsoft Access. Before I start there are some important features I want to make sure are available in Access.

1. In a multi-user environment can the database be accessed simultaneously by different users such that only individual records are locked/unlocked as necessary?
2. Does Access need to be "opened" or can a "front end" be designed so the user only sees menus, menu bars, tabs, data screens, etc?
3. Can the database design features be locked so the user cannot change any database features?

Thank you for your help.
AF

Answer (score 4):

- Yes, certain records can be locked. 
  For Example, if you work with an ADO Recordset:

  recordset.Open Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options

LockType defines the locking-mechanism used for the selected Query `Source`.
More Information on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

- Usually you split your Database into an frontend and backend. The back-end only contains only the tables, the rest goes in to the frontend. The backend tables are then linked to the frontend. Here is a link explaining how to do that: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/DatabaseSplitter/
- In the frontend file can be compiled, so that the frontend users cannot edit sources.

Comment: Thanks. Those links are will be very helpful.

Comment: I see two people commented I should avoid Access. I'm wondering what the problems would be and would using Visual Studio be more appropriate?

Comment: I developed an Access Application for a client. It is currenty in use by 6-7 Users. I think for such small scales, Access should suffice. For larger scales, you could always "upscale" to a SQL Server backend with Access or /.NET frontend.

Comment: I would be deloping this for several clients non of which are over 7 (with expansion perhaps to at most 10 users.) If I understand your comment I could design this in Access and then if necessary just port it over to SQL server with appropriate (minor?) changes.

Comment: I only tried porting it to SQL Server in a testing environment, not in prod, but it worked without changes to the code. There is an “Upscaling assistant“ for that, but you can,do it by hand. What you do is exporting the backend to SQL Server and link to the sql server tables in the frontend.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Access. It fills an important niche, not only for the initial outlay but also for continued support in small companies that don't have a full-time database developer.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the third of your initial questions please note that Microsoft Access offers the facility to convert an Access database to an executable file (having file extension "accde" where your forms, reports, code and macros are protected to a substantial extent. However the level of protection offered with regard to tables is low in that the same are directly accessible even in an accde. MS Access also offers the runtime version free of charge and does not restrict its deployment to as many users as you may require. It no longer offers user-level security. This feature has been replaced with an encrypted password feature. Thus you will have to insert your own design and code to impose access restrictions on different categories of users. Alternatively, to use the user level security feature, one has to develop his application in an earlier version of Access in which this feature was available and thereafter use a recent version to convert it. I am uncertain whether MS Access 2013 will entertain such a database but understand that MS 2010 will though it will not offer that feature when you create a new database inside it.

Answer (score -1):

You can get SQL Express for free, it's a stripped down version of SQL Server. It will handle multiple user access significantly better and not come with the bloat/performance degredation issues that Access brings along.

There will be a slightly higher learning curve, but if you're looking to get your foot into the development world's door, you'll be much better off learning how to work with SQL Server than Access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been writing code since 1979. I started on an Apple II.  I've currently got an application written MS QuickBasic (yes for DOS.) I would like to rewrite for a Windows environment but I'll probably only be in the business another 5-6 years so I'ld like to use something with a quick learning curve but also stability and reliability. Over the years I've written some small programs in VB but haven't tackled the conversion of my DOS program (currently about 15000-20000 lines of code.)

Comment: Do tell, what part of SQL Express replaces the rapid deployment part of Access? Does SQL Express suddenly come with report and forms design? Access is not a database, it usually, but not always, uses Jet/ACE as a database. Please see the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/info

Comment: While this answer might be a part of addressing subquestion #1, there has been no effort made to actually be explicit about it. This is not in any way a suitable or helpful answer for any part of the question being asked.